# Reference column in a table on another server in an UPDATE/JOIN (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, join, naming

I'm familiar with 4-part naming, but I get an error every time I try to reference a column.  For example:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET my_table.column1 = otherserver.otherdatabase.dbo.othertable.column1
FROM my_table INNER JOIN otherserver.otherdatabase.dbo.othertable
ON my_table.column2 = otherserver.otherdatabase.dbo.othertable.column2
```

This throws the following error:

> The multi-part identifier "otherserver.otherdatabase.dbo.othertable.column1" could not be bound.

I never have trouble if I am only reference a table, but when I append the column name, it always throws an error.  Any ideas?  SQL Server 2008

Comment: can you see `select column1 from otherserver.otherdatabase.dbo.othertable`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the table name when you qualify your columns.

```
UPDATE my_table
SET my_table.column1 = othertable.column1
FROM my_table INNER JOIN otherserver.otherdatabase.dbo.othertable
ON my_table.column2 = othertable.column2
```

Or use an alias.

```
UPDATE my_table
SET my_table.column1 = OT.column1
FROM my_table INNER JOIN otherserver.otherdatabase.dbo.othertable as OT
ON my_table.column2 = OT.column2
```

Comment: It worked!  I knew there was an easy way to do this.  Thanks!!

Comment: Thank you, this was driving me nuts. I was forgetting the schema(dbo) part!

Answer (score 1):

Use table alias then access the column:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET my_table.column1 = A.column1
FROM my_table INNER JOIN otherserver.otherdatabase.dbo.othertable A
ON my_table.column2 = A.column2
```